# AppWidget with Background image + Text + click (tap) event

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing an AppWidget on which I must programatically control it's background image. Additionally, I must display [overlaying] text messages. I must also react to user interaction ("clicks").
My (already working) proof-of-concept is as follows:

a) I have an ImageButton on my main layout.
b) I have a custom intent that I'm processing onReceive(). I then change it's background image via RemoteViews.setImageViewResource method. This works almost fine, except for the fact that I cannot have/set text on a ImageButton.
 
c) I replaced a) by a Button. I now can write text to the Button, but I cannot find a way to change it's background image.

So I'm basically stuck on a loop: I could not find a way yet to accomplish all the three goals on my appWidget: an image + clickable + with text.

Since I'm new to Android, I ask you folks for some pointers/directions.
Thanks in advance
Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Create a layout with a `LinearLayout` (or whatever) and a `TextView`.

Step #2: Use the above layout for your app widget, putting your background on the `LinearLayout`, your text in the `TextView`, and your click `PendingIntents` on one or both (you didn't indicate what is supposed to be clicked).

Step #3: There is no step #3.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare for the magic phrase "...on one or both...". I did some experiments with TextViews also, but I totally overlooked the fact that I can set PendingIntent on several places. It was mostly a mindset issue + newcomer to this platform. Cheers, Pedro.

Comment: I'm controlling my Intents now, but I still cannot change my layout's background programmatically. I've googled this extensively, and it seems that it's not possible. Is having multiple layouts (each with it's bg image) and setting their visibility the cleanest option? Thanks.

Comment: @pfonseca: You can call `setBackgroundColor()` and `setBackgroundResource()` via `setInt()` on the `RemoteViews`. Beyond that, easiest solution probably is separate layout files per background and choose the right one when you create your `RemoteViews`. You could do

Comment: Thanks for following up, @CommonsWare. Sure, setInt() seems straightforward as I dive deeper into the AppWidgets paradigm. However I achieved my goal by using separate layout files. Best regards.